# Sessions "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, null

While working on a sessions feature for my website I have ran into this following error in my session views

[rails sessions error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnDhr.png)

here is the following code for my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new 
  end

  def create
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
      if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
          redirect_to @user
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Failed to login, please try again"
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

My sessions helper method:

```
 module SessionsHelper

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end
end
```

and for the views:

```
 <h1>Log In</h1>

<%= form_for(@user, url: login_path) do |f|%>

<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email%><br>
<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password%><br>
<%= f.submit "Log In", class: "btn btn-primary", style: "width: 200px" %>
<%end%>
```

My user sign up path is working fine and creating instances of the user class. The error occurs when a user fills out the log in form and hits the submit button, which then should redirect them to their profile. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
    @user = User.new if @user.blank?

    ##rest of your logic comes here
  end

end
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
   <%= form_for(@user = User.new , url: login_path) do |f|%>
```

Comment: If you could please add a short explanation about why your suggestion should solve the problem that will increase your contribution's value to the site.